# Identification green plane-tail-like pieces

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Any idea from which set these pieces do come from?

[image: green plane-tail-like pieces]

Comment: Welcome to Brick.SE.  Thanks for the clear picture with a nice background of a different color than the part. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are Sand Green [Tail Shuttle](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6239&in=S) pieces, found only in [2509: Earth Dragon Defense](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2509-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) - exactly 4 pieces per set:
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity how did you identify them?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I recognized the shuttle tail piece from my own Space Shuttle set, and started with looking up 2x3 modified plates. There were way too much of those, so I focused on the colour instead and got a hunch that it has Ninjago dragon vibes. From there it was quite straightforward.